# Data Import on Solr Failing with SQLException: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: solr

When I am trying to Full Import in Solr getting below Exception :

SEVERE: getNext() failed for query 'SELECT * from my_app.my_solr_app_vw':org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:63)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.hasnext(JdbcDataSource.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.access$600(JdbcDataSource.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator$1.hasNext(JdbcDataSource.java:261)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorBase.getNext(EntityProcessorBase.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:472)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:411)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:326)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:234)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:382)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:448)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:429)

    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mistake in your query. Something like

```
select ... from ... where field = (select ... from ... where ...)
```

but the subquery returned more than one row.